# Counting from low input to high input by 100's using for loop

Tags: c++

I am attempting to construct a for loop for a tax table I am making. If the user inputs 500 as the upper bound value and 100 as the lowerbound value the program should print

200
300
400
500

however the code I have written

```
for (int i = lowerbound + 100; upperbound>=i; i++){
     cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

would output 200,201,202....500 then the program will stop. I assumed that lowerbound or the low entry + 100 would cause the loop to add 100 to the output every time and then print and then return to the loop. What am I doing wrong? Should the + 100 only exist outside of the for loop? If so how would I execute that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i++` in your example could simply be `i += 100` to continually add 100 to `i`.

Comment: you are a savior thank you so much. It makes sense now! I was just adding 100 to the initializer instead of the counter!

Answer (score 0):

For loops have three components: In order, the initializer, the comparitor, and the incrementor.

The incrementor in your loop is `i++;`, so each go round adds one to i, hence you get 200, 201, 202...

Just change the incrementor to read `i += 100;`, which will add 100 each go-round